# How to load a nested Map in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a nested Map inside a Map. I am trying to do the following:

```
    LinkedHashMap<Modifier, Map<Toping,bool>> toppings;
    toppings = Map();
      menuItem.modifiers.forEach((modifier) {
      toppings[modifier] = LinkedHashMap();
      toppings[modifier].addAll({ for (final top in modifier.topings) top : false });
        //toppings[modifier] = Map.from({ for (final top in modifier.topings) top : false });
      });
```

I am getting the following error..

```
Expected a value of type 'LinkedHashMap<Modifier, Map<Toping, bool>>', but got one of type 'LinkedMap<dynamic, dynamic>'
```

Answer (score 1):

try to declare generic type while initializing variable to

```
toppings = Map<Modifier, Map<Toping,bool>>();
```

try to add strict rules to your **analysis_options.yaml**

Answer (score 0):

The problem got resolved by changing the following line:

```
toppings = Map();
```

to

```
toppings = LinkedHashMap();
```

But I am not sure why this happened as toppings are already declared as LinkedHashMap.